# Group near-points into a single weighted point (dynamically)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, cartography, overlapping-features, visualisation

I have a point feature class that is constantly being updated. The points are clustered, so I would like to display near-points as a single, weighted point (and symbolize accordingly). Related information here: [Visualize overlapping points](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/230824/visualize-overlapping-points)

I can do this with the [`Collect Events`](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-statistics-toolbox/collect-events.htm) geo-processing tool. However, this geo-processing tool produces a static output feature class; it is not dynamic.

Is there a way to dynamically symbolize near-points as a single point in ArcMap?

This is commonly done in web maps, so there *must* be a way for a platform as powerful as ArcGIS Desktop to do this, *right*?

Comment: I am not aware of a dynamic way of doing this in ArcGIS Desktop.  It *might* be possible with ArcGIS Pro.  I produce the static weighted points using [Optimized Hot Spot Analysis](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-statistics-toolbox/optimized-hot-spot-analysis.htm)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use point clustering as shown in [this sample web map](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/sandbox/sandbox.html?sample=layers_point_clustering), with Esri products it's only possible with the ArcGIS API for JavaScript and with ArcGIS Online.

There is an Esri Idea asking to add this functionality in Desktop: [Cluster Rendering for ArcMap](https://geonet.esri.com/ideas/5998). All you can do is vote for it...